# Check for precompiled headers with autotools?

Tags: c++, gcc, autotools, autoconf, precompiled-headers

How can I check if gcc precompiled headers are supported with autoconf? Is there a macro like AC_CHECK_GCH? The project I'm working on has a lot of templates and includes, I have tried writing a .h with the most commonly used includes and compiling it manually. It could be nice to integrate it with the rest of autotools.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are hoping to accomplish.  Are you hoping to distribute a precompiled header in your tarball?  doing so would be almost completely useless.  (I actually think it would be completely useless, but I say "almost" because I might be missing something.)
The system headers on the target box (the machine on which your project is being built) are almost certainly different than the ones on your development box.  If they are the same, then there's no need to be using autoconf.

If the user of your package happens to be using gcc and wants to use precompiled headers, then they will put the .gch files in the appropriate location and gcc will use them.  You don't need to do anything in your package.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to distribute precompiled headers, but to check during configure if the gcc of the user can create them.

Comment: @Helltone  Why do you want to know?  If the user wants to use pre-compiled headers, he will set up his system to do so.  What will you do differently in your package if they are available?